Show Excel column letters in Report Builder / SSRS design
Challenge: During feedback, end users often reference the column letters seen after export to Excel, though we don't see these in the SSRS design itself.
Example: "I would like to move column M to be before column D". Another example, a late Friday cryptic panic email from overburdened upper management "Column kk isn't populating!"
We'd like to be able to see these letters in a hidden row in table designs. Is there a way to auto-populate these so that when we move columns the letters are updated to match the new order?
I've surfed for answers, but found only ways to number rows, not ways to letter columns.

You want this to occur at design-time?

Unless you report is really simple, just a single table then you might end up with columns hidden in excel that have been added to mimic the layout in the report designer. Even if it is just a simple table you'd have to add the column letters in the design somehow. If I veer get request like this, I aske them to send me a copy of the report and highlight the bit that they are talking about.

@RossBush: Yes, I was hoping to see it in the design, though now that I think about it, in practice results of an expression wouldn't show until execution, so not quite as handy as I'd hoped. After four years of work-from-home I'm very recently and happily back in an office, so for those that work in my building maybe they can just point at my screens. :-)

@AlanSchofield: I would hide the header row in output based on UserID. Our users aren't consistent with using confidential email when they send examples from our all-HIPPA data, which can be nerve-wracking.
